# MYSQLI For calculating people with only one record in table?

Tags: php, mysqli, subquery, analytics

I have been stuck on this FOREVER and I would be so grateful for another perspective. I have a table tracking website views and need to query the number of people who visited one page only. My Table is similar to below:

```
SESSION_ID     PAGE
------------------------
122            HOME
122            CONTACT US
123            HOME
124            HOME
```

I need a way to **count the number of sessions that only show up once in the table** (only viewed one page). IE: In the above: what query would tell me that 2 people viewed only one page.

I would love to post what I have tried, but I honestly have no clue where to start. I am thinking something like:

```
$query=mysqli_query(con,"SELECT count PAGE as pages_viewed FROM analytics WHERE pages_viewed='1' GROUP BY SESSION ID");
$singleViewRows= mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

But I don't think that is it? Maybe I need a subquery in there?

Thank you again for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, we are interested in the number of session here, so counting pages wouldn't give the expected result.

So what about the following query:

```
SELECT session_id, COUNT(session_id) FROM analytics GROUP BY session_id HAVING COUNT(session_id) = 1
```

Selecting COUNT(session_id) is optional but it'll give you the confirmation you fetched only the ones with 1 record in the table.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.